Alembic particles exported freeze
Problems with the export and import of alembic animations.
I do something similar. as in the tutor. The author uses animation export of particle system in alembic. Then this animation is imported to a new file. Everything works fast  fast for him.
https://youtu.be/CrOboutVHH8?si=c__eyvaaQsMj0QAF&t=636
Everything slows me down a lot. The my system is down. Freeze.
This is despite the fact that the author of this video uses a million particles, and I use only 10 thousand.
Why can there be such problems?
I have Ryzen 7, 32 GB of RAM and RTX3050


The question can be closed. Since he used the icosphere as particles, and the author used the halo. In the latter case, everything works fine
